# How to dynamically set the margin-left value of a an HTML element based on a value in the Rails view?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

My Rails app generates nested comments and tracks their depth using a `depth` variable. I can see that this variable is generating the appropriate values because I can read it in the comment_layout view with this piece of code `<%= comment.depth %>`, however, it is not giving me any results when I try to use it to set the value of the `margin-left` when I use it in the pertinent `<div>`, like so:

```
<div class="c-margin" style="margin-left: <%= comment.depth * 4 %>px;">
  <%= comment.depth %>
  <%= comment.body %>
</div>
```

I cannot explain what might be the issue here. Much obliged to anyone that can point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What do you see in inspector? May be you have some CSS rule, that override it, as debug try `style="margin-left: <%= comment.depth * 4 %>px !important;"`

Comment: What type does `comment.depth` return? Is it an integer value?

Comment: @mechnicov doesn't the inline css override anything else, by virtue of the css specificity rules? Am I wrong?

Comment: @LesNightingill it depends. If some "parent" rule has `!important` property, but inline hasn't, it will not override "parent"

Comment: If you open inspector and hover over your div, are you sure that the margin hasn't been added? Maybe it gets a margin but it doesn't show because of some other rule on surrounding elements.

Comment: A tip is to use the tag helpers instead of doing ERB interpolation insideof the attributes of a HTML tag. `<%= tag.div class: "c-margin", style: "margin-left: #{ comment.depth * 4}px;" do %> ...`. This is more readible.